# Call recording using AT+CRCPREC SIM COM 800

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, at-command, sim900

I want to record current call on my sim 800 modem, as per [Tutorial](http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/docs/simcom/docs/sim5215-16/simcom_sim5215_sim5216_atc_en_v1.21.pdf) page 135

```
AT+CQCPREC= 0,amr
C:/Audio/20080520_120303.amr
```

command is used for recording but it gives response `Error`. What can be the possible reason. As "error" don't specify what can be the possible reason. Other command like ATD, ATH are working perfect it means modem is working perfect. For firing AT command i am using Tera Term.

Comment: Try to list any commands and their responses that you are sending before this as well

Comment: Did you fix it? How do you defines the C directory in the raspberry-pi?